# JAVA - create objects from abstract class depending on arguments

Tags: java, class, constructor, abstract

I'm 100% positive that this has been asked before, but I don't know what to google:

Suppose I have an abstract class Ngram that's basically just a List:

```
abstract class Ngram {
private List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
... }
```

Is it now possible to create an object of subclass Unigram, Bigram... depending on the parameter n? Something like this:

```
int n;
for(Word w : Sentence.getWordList()) {
Ngram ngram = new Ngram(n); 
... }
```

So the constructor of Ngram would look something like this:

```
Ngram(int n) {
if(n==1) : //create Object of Type Unigram, let ngram refer to this object
}
```

I tried to return a new Unigram, but that doesn't work. I guess it's not the greatest idea to let the constructor of the abstract super class do this, but I don't how to tackle this problem. Any tips are appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pattern for exactly this, a `Factory`.

```
class Ngram { }
class Ugram extends Ngram { }
class Bigram extends Ngram { }

public class NgramFactory {
    public static Ngram createNgram(int n) {
        if (n ==1) {
            return new Ugram();
        } else {
            return new Bigram();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `NgramFactory.createNgram(x)`

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Ngram createNgram(int n){
    switch(n){
    case 1:
        return new Unigram();
    case 2:
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, that's actually a really nice way to avoid all of the if(n==...) else if() statements, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Factory`-Pattern to let you create new Objects based on your parameter